# Issue trying to filter long numbers

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column with lots of longer numbers in it. I want to filter my column for all numbers that DO NOT begin with 2. I tried writing it in code to select all of the 2's first, but that didn't work. Then I tried to do it by hand in Excel by saying filter, custom rule, does not begin with 2. But nothing changes. I don't see, for example, a zero before the numbers either. I tried to reformat them into numbers but they were already numbers. I am not sure why it isn't selecting either all the numbers that start with 2 or all the numbers that DON'T start with 2.

Here is the code I tried to get numbers that START with 2.

```
With ws1.Range("A1:Z" & UsdRws)
    .autofilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="2*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    On Error Resume Next

    UsdRws = ws1.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If UsdRws > 1 Then
        Range("A2:A" & UsdRws).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    .autofilter Field:=9
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
```

The filter does not change anything even though I have a lot of numbers beginning with 2. Here is a sample of the numbers I am using.

```
2190190000
1410650400
1410720000
1410511900
1410650000
1410511900
1410650500
1410680100
1410650300
2190160000
1410650100
2190160000
2020110008
1410511900
1410650400
2020110002
2020180000
2010110100
1410671000
2190190000
1410650200
2020180000
2190190000
1410650400
1410720000
1410511900
1410650000
1410511900
1410650500
```

So like I said, I am trying to get either all the numbers beginning with 2 or all the other ones, but it seems like neither is working, even when doing it by hand using a custom filter rule.

Comment: It looks like I can use greater than 2000000000 to get the numbers beginning with 2's but I would rather not do it like that because there are also numbers higher than that that I do not want.

Comment: easiest way will be to have a helper column and filter the data on that.

Comment: "Begins with a '2'" is something you'd say of a `String`, not of a number. Make another column with `=TEXT(A2,"@")` for a formula (or `="'" & A2`), fill down, and filter on *that* column.

Comment: Filter on >= 2000000000 and < 3000000000.  (Using the macro recorder shows me that can be done as `Criteria1:=">=2000000000", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<3000000000"`)

Comment: @YowE3K Hey there. Yeah I actually ended up doing it like that and I believe that will actually work just fine. It has so far and I don't think anything should break it.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks for your help. That makes a lot of sense and I will keep that in mind for the future. I was just surprised that it didn't work, but then I could filter using a custom rule inbetween 2000000000 and 3000000000 and it worked for that. But I guess that makes sense about it being a string. It looks like it works now by putting it into another column and putting it into text. If you want to make it an answer I will mark it correct : )

Comment: Meh, @cyboashu had the idea 2 whole minutes before I did :)

Comment: Eh maybe but I didn't understand his answer as well as yours. I would not have known to put it into text just from his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of your numbers are 10 digit numbers, then the following seems to work:

```
Option Explicit
Sub FilterTwos()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim r As Range

Set ws1 = Worksheets("sheet1")
With ws1
    Set r = .Range("a2", Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
End With

ws1.AutoFilterMode = False

r.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=2000000000", Operator:=xlAnd, _
    Criteria2:="<3000000000"

Set r = r.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
r.Copy Worksheets("sheet2").Range("B2")

End Sub
```

Comment: I did not use this code exactly but the idea of filtering inbetween those numbers did work for me. Thank you for writing the whole code out. The other answer of copying the column into text then filtering using that also works. But I think filtering in between these numbers will actually be easier.

Comment: Glad to help. If the numbers are not equal length, then a simple filter won't work, although you could use an Advanced Filter

Answer (score 1):

In your With statement you use UsdRws but don't give UsdRws a value until within the 'With'. May this be causing your problem?

You could also try treating the numbers as strings (change format to text?). This way Excel shouldn't get confused by what it thinks you should or shouldn't be able to do with numbers.

Comment: my UsdRws is declared farther up sorry about that. But someone else recommended that it is because it is a string like you mentioned and I think that probably makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

This works regardless of how many digits your numbers contain. Your `inputRange` should just be the column with the long numbers in, include headers too.

```
Sub Remove2()
    Dim inputRange As Range
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim i As Long, deleteCount As Long, min As Long

    Set inputRange = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10001")
    v = inputRange.Value
    min = Application.WorksheetFunction.min(inputRange) - 1

    For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        If Left(v(i, 1), 1) = "2" Then
            v(i, 1) = min
            deleteCount = deleteCount + 1
        End If
    Next i

    With inputRange
        .Value = v
        .Sort key1:=.Resize(1, 1), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes 'xlNo if no headers
        .Resize(deleteCount, 1).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete 'remove offset if no headers
    End With
End Sub
```

*tested with 10,000 numbers taking 0.4 seconds*

Comment: Thank you for your time. This is a very interesting approach. I did not end up using this but I will keep it in mind for the future. Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: No problem, it is particularly useful when you have more complicated criteria. For example the filtering suggested by others wouldn't have worked if some of your numbers weren't 10 digits long (as also noted by others).